# Setting common tags with Micrometer for InfluxDB metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, influxdb, spring-micrometer

I have a separate module which contains common classes. Two of the classes are setting up common tags for metrics for our services. When I start the service the metrics (counters) are sent to the InfluxDb, but the common tags, that are set in MetricsConfiguration.java are not being sent. I have queried the metrics in the InfluxDb as well and tags like `service` and `env` are not there, all others that are set directly with counters are.

I am pretty fresh with Spring, Spring Boot and Micrometer. Either I misunderstood the documentation and configuration of common tags or they are not supported within counters or InfluxDb in general?

Version of Micrometer: `compile group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-influx', version: '1.0.5'`

Checking the `/configprops` endpoint I can see:

```
...
"metrics-com.example.io.metrics.MetricsProperties": {
    "prefix": "metrics",
    "properties": {
        "step": 0,
        "histogramExpiry": 0,
        "serviceTag": "service"
    }
}
...
```

and `/env/spring.application.name` gives:

```
...
"property": {
    "source": "applicationConfig: [classpath:/bootstrap.yml]",
    "value": "example-service"
},
...
```

Even setting this in config properties, does not seem to have any effect:

```
environment: development

...

management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      env: "${environment}"
...
```

Checking endpoint `/env/management.metrics.tags.env` it shows `development`.

With `/beans` endpoint, I can see beans being loaded:

```
...
"metricsCommonTags": {
    "aliases": [],
    "scope": "singleton",
    "type": "com.example.io.metrics.MetricsConfiguration$$Lambda$325/509806761",
    "resource": "com.example.io.metrics.MetricsConfiguration",
    "dependencies": []
},
"metricsConfiguration": {
    "aliases": [],
    "scope": "singleton",
    "type": "com.example.io.metrics.MetricsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f1b7dc1a",
    "resource": null,
    "dependencies": [
        "metrics-com.example.io.metrics.MetricsProperties",
        "org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ed3b1f5"
    ]
},
...
"metrics-com.example.io.metrics.MetricsProperties": {
    "aliases": [],
    "scope": "singleton",
    "type": "com.example.io.metrics.MetricsProperties",
    "resource": null,
    "dependencies": []
},
...
```

So my question is am I missing something?

**MetricsProperties.java**

```
package com.example.io.metrics;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "metrics")
public class MetricsProperties {
    private int histogramExpiry;
    private int step;
    private String serviceTag;

    public int getHistogramExpiry() {
        return histogramExpiry;
    }

    public void setHistogramExpiry(int histogramExpiry) {
        this.histogramExpiry = histogramExpiry;
    }

    public int getStep() {
        return step;
    }

    public void setStep(int step) {
        this.step = step;
    }

    public String getServiceTag() {
        return serviceTag;
    }

    public void setServiceTag(String serviceTag) {
        this.serviceTag = serviceTag;
    }
}
```

**MetricsConfiguration.java**

```
package com.example.io.metrics;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MetricsProperties.class)
public class MetricsConfiguration {

    private final MetricsProperties metricsProperties;

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public MetricsConfiguration(MetricsProperties metricsProperties, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.metricsProperties = metricsProperties;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> registry
                .config()
                .commonTags(metricsProperties.getServiceTag(),
                        applicationContext.getApplicationName());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So we also have `/META-INF/spring.factories` filled with:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration = com.example.io.autoconfigure.CustomConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration\
  ,com.example.io.metrics.MetricsConfiguration
```

The `CustomConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration` is getting skiped locally because there is `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "autoconfigure.client.resolvePrivateServerAddress", matchIfMissing = true)` condition and in `bootstrap.yml` there is

```
autoconfigure:
  client:
    resolvePrivateServerAddress: false
```

I did also some research and what I found out that `metricsCommonTags` bean might of been called before the context is initialised, but I am not sure about that? What is weird is that, when I put a breakpoint in the `metricsCommonTags`, the properties are not yet set from Cloud Config server.

Here is also trimmed down version of `Application.java`:

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LoginProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public Application(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For all other stuff where we use properties from Cloud Config server they are being initialised just fine.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No. I have used a lot of time debugging it, but I did not solve it.

Comment: I solved it using code...posted below

Answer (score 1):

I used below code to add common tags to all metrics being sent to InfluxDB

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;

@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    String applicationName;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
                    String hostname = "";
                    try {
                        hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().toString();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        hostname = "unknown";
                    }
                    List<Tag> tags = new LinkedList<>();
                    tags.add(Tag.of("hostname", hostname));
                    tags.add(Tag.of("applicationName", applicationName));
                    String activeProfiles = Arrays.stream(this.environment.getActiveProfiles()).reduce("",String::concat);
                    tags.add(Tag.of("environment", activeProfiles));
                    return registry -> registry.config().commonTags(tags);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks. I got a question is there any specific reason to use LinkedList instead of ArrayList?